# Can I force the Open Recent list in IntelliJ to be sorted alphabetically?

Tags: intellij-idea

IntelliJ lists recent projects in the File -> Open Recent by date of last access - which is maddening if you have more than 3 or 4 recent projects. Is there a way to force the sorting of this list to be alphabetical?

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately, it's [not](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-146633/Project-management-allow-to-sort-projects-in-alphabeticalrecent-order) [possible](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-187869/Feature-to-reorder-projects-inside-project-groups-in-Recent-Projects) at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

no, Bug IDEA-146633 since more than 8 years open for this feature...

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-146633/Project-management-allow-to-sort-projects-in-alphabetical-recent-order